# Angular 2 and SEO meta tags

Tags: angular, seo, keyword

I have Angular 2 web site and I want to add meta tags (keywords)
What is the best?

- To put all keywords into Index.html page?
- To put separate tags for each component via .ts code (@angular/platform-browser)?

Are there some difference for the searching machines?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The right solution would be to handle this at the component's level and using services provided by Angular like this:

```
import { Meta, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Meta for meta tags like description and keywords and title for the html title

e.g.

```
constructor(private titleService: Title, private metaService: Meta) {}


this.metaService.addTags([
  { name: 'keywords', content: 'Keyword1, Keyword2' },
  { name: 'description', content: 'Your SEO desc' },
]);


this.titleService('Your seo title');
```

Putting your meta tags into index.html would mean that you would have the same title, description and keywords for all pages within your app and if it is publicly available website that would be disadvantageous from the SEO point of view.

Comment: please remove the part where you state that `Putting your meta tags into index.html would mean that you would have the same title, description and keywords for all pages within your app `. Because this is NOT true. I just tested it myself by putting a title and keywords in `index.html` while immediately changing the keywords and title using `Meta` and `Title` once the angular app was loaded. Both the title and keywords were successfully changed after the app rendered. I could see this change both in the source code and in the title text of the open browser tab.

Comment: If you change the meta tags with the described services they will obviously be changed - this is what they are for. I only meant that setting the meta tags in index.html and not changing them dynamically would result in having the same meta tags on each page.